# How can I find the new iCloud address of a mobileme website?

Tags: icloud, mobileme

I need to access a previously public webpage on mobileme. Since that site is closed and merged to iCloud, is there any way to find out if the site has been migrated, and if so, what the new address is?

Comment: Why was this question closed instead of being migrated to Ask Different, where it IS on topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web hosting function Apple provided was [shut down](http://www.macrumors.com/2011/06/12/steve-jobs-confirms-discontinuation-of-iweb-in-icloud-transition/) not "merged."  There is no iCloud address for old mobile me websites.  Public websites were backed up by an outside company, but I don't have their information.